# Sendmail to filter custom header

Tags: linux, sendmail

we have mail server which relays mails which has only internal domains( lets say @osp.com, @asp.com) to external world via following configuraiton in my mailertable configuration of sendmail . Any email to other domain is rejected . The current requirement is to relay email if specific custom header for ex: "X-Test" exists in the email headers and if sent from any other email domain ( which are currently denied ) .

I have considered using rulesets , the closest one I have got is the below link but it is not useful , I am not asking for a solution but seeking directions . I have understood so far how the rules/rulesets are written ( bit complex one though in sendmail ).

```
osp.net           smtp:ms.osp.net
asp.net           smtp:ms.osp.net
.                 procmail:/etc/mail/reject-mail.proc
```

Related link:
http://bradthemad.org/tech/notes/sendmail_header_filter.php

Answer (score 0):

"allow only if set" is much more complicated then the linked "deny if
set" example; the "deny if set" simply rejects the message when the
header has a particular value. The "allow only if set" must instead mark
appropriate messages as allowed, but then also somewhere else deny all
other messages. Another complication for the "allow only if set" is the
possibility of system messages (e.g. those from cron) that may also need
to be allowed, in which case a blanket deny will not suffice. Yet
another concern is whether your systems allow remote relay; if so and if
the ruleset is crafted incorrectly you could turn your servers into open
relays for anyone who sets the header field in question. That could be
bad, and unless you strip out the test header somewhere, it will be
visible to anyone who can read messages from your system.

One method would be to check at the end of headers whether `X-Test` has
been seen; if not, reject the message. This will fail system messages
that do not have the header set, but should not turn the system into an
open relay as various other rulesets should still apply to detemine 
relaying rights. Thus in `sendmail.mc` add something like:

```
LOCAL_RULESETS
Kstorage macro
HX-Test: $>CheckTestHeader

SCheckTestHeader
R$*                     $: $(storage {xtestsetp} $@ OK $) $1

Scheck_eoh
R$*                     $: < $&{xtestsetp} >
R$*                     $: $(storage {xtestsetp} $) $1
R< $+ >                 $@ OK
R$*                     $#error $: 553 Missing Header
```

and rebuild `sendmail.cf`, restart `sendmail`, send test messages with
and without the test header.

Those runs of "lots of spaces" must be replaced one or more tab
characters, as Sendmail is one of those unfortunate softwares that
mandates the use of significant whitespace (crazy, I know, but
here we are).

For more information on this example see section 5.1.4.6 in the Sendmail
`op.pdf` manual, from which the above is more or less cribbed.

Note also that the above should only be used on outgoing mail server
configurations, as it will reject incoming mail that does not have
the required header.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable inputs , I  will try to configure and check. Cheers

Comment: I have a query how does the precdence of rules takes place , i.e even though we implement this rule how to ensure that rule based on "/etc/mail/mailertable"  wont hinder the current X-test header ruleset . **Kmailertable hash -o /etc/mail/mailertable.db
R< $+ > $*              $: < $(mailertable $1 $) > $2   lookup **

Answer (score 0):

@thrig thanks once again for your suggestions.
I have to understand how the rules are being written and hence took this time. I have modified the ruleset given ( as I need to allow the header rather than stop) , so the following lines are added to sendmail.mc and I get the desired result . I am yet to test this in our pre-prod farm though but this have given me some insight on how to go foward .

I have created a small python script which help me in creating the headers that I need and send them . The below ruleset Allows "X-Test" header which is my requirement as my mailertable rejects any other emails based on the domains listed earlier .
Appreicate if you feedback with any flaws .

LOCAL_RULESETS
Kstorage macro
HX-Test: $>CheckTestHeader

SCheckTestHeader
R$*     $: $(storage {xtestsetp} $@ OK $) $1
R< $+ > $@ OK

## R$*    $#error $: 553 Missing Header  --> [ This is for testing  ]